# Define number of occurances on Google or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

I am trying to build a very simple test case with Google Or-tools on Python. I have a list of 20 slots which are integer variables, and the only constraint I am trying to set is that each of the values from 0 to 4 is seen 3 times.

For example, this would be a solution:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

I tried the following example:

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

solver = pywrapcp.Solver("test")

num_profs = 5
num_slots = 20

prof_variables = [solver.IntVar(-1, num_profs, "slot{}.prof".format(i)) for i in range(num_slots)]

for prof in range(num_profs):
    solver.Add(solver.Sum([prof_variables[i] == prof for i in range(num_slots)]) == 3)

db = solver.Phase(prof_variables, solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND, solver.ASSIGN_MIN_VALUE)
#tl = solver.TimeLimit(10000)
solver.NewSearch(db)

count = 0
while solver.NextSolution():
    count += 1
    print("Time:", solver.WallTime(), "ms")
    print()

    print("Solution " + str(count))
    for i in range(num_slots):
        print(prof_variables[i].Value())

    if count > 2:
        break

solver.EndSearch()
```

However, it does not find any solution (And never completes if I don't put a time limit).

If I remove the constraint with `Sum`, this completes (there is no constraint at all).

As this constraint is pretty trivial, I expect that the way I write the it is not correct. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I noticed that I can replace the ``Sum`` function by ``Count(prof_variables, prof, 3)`` which is more explicit, but it does not solve the problem. I also tried that if I try to have 1 or 2 occurances instead of 3 it completes quite quickly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial, I think I came to a partial conclusion. I did not look for the mathematical proof, but trying to play with some parameters, it looks like that this algorithm's time is exponential. Too much choices means that the tool is not able to find a single solution, while a very constrained system will be solved very quickly.

For my specific case, I was able to advance by changing the way I attacked the problem. For example I was able to split to 2 phases:

- A first phase for which I attached 'prof' values to 'classes', given constraints that are given. More than 600k solutions are found, but this is very quick (Around 600ms)
- A second phase to attach prof/classe to slots, for which quite a lot of constraints exist when we have the link prof/classe.

It also looks like that the way we express the problem is really key, and the tools needs enough constraints to be able to restrict the solutions very quickly.